# Did the moderator elections finish?

Tags: support, election, moderators

I saw a couple of unusual diamonds around today, but no META posts about the election results. Did I miss something important between working and trying to answer questions?

(if so, I would congratulate the new moderators but I have even less clue who they are than Lois Lane about true identity of Superman)

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/election

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically there is a banner that pops up on the main site, linking to the [election site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/). Not sure what happened...

Comment: Why don't you put it up now? :)

Comment: @Kevin - he's a Doctor, not a Moderator, dammit Jim! Uh... never mind...

Comment: @Kevin: Pretty much I've been told that while moderators can put up a system message, don't do it...

Comment: @Kevin There was a banner to announce the election, so that people could participate. There's no need for an announcement that the elections are over; anyone interested can browse the election page.